# I want to schedule a test in different date with various user login in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, scheduler

I want the following scenario to setup in Jmeter. Can you please suggest ways?

Test start time: 27th August 9.00am
Test End time: 27th August 11.00am
Every 30 min, 1 user logs in and does 1 transaction and logout. So in total there will be 4 transactions in 2 hours.

How to set this in Jmeter? Experts pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Plan structure (replace Debug Sampler by your sampler):

[image: Test Plan]

Thread Group config

[image: Thread Group config]

Test Action config:

[image]

Timer config:

[image]

Also add a CsvDataset that will contain logins and maybe add cookie manager depending on what's in your test

Read reference docs to understand:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html